# Django-Debug-toolbar: No module named setuptools

Tags: python, django, installation

I am trying to install Django-Debug-toolbar.

I have downloaded the .tar file and done the two extractions. Then I have placed the extracted folder somewhere and done what I always do, which is to cd to the folder containing setup.py and then execute

```
python setup.py install
```

I get an error "No module named setuptools". Do I really need to download and install something else just to install this? I have installed all my other packages in this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I installed distribute http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute and then was able to install the debug tool bar, which is now working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have in install either setuptools or distribute, but the recommended step is to install distribute, since setuptools isn`t avaliable for Python 3 and beyond, which is experimentally available since Django 1.5.